# How to update a document in MongoDb with the field value itself in iterations?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a MongoDb document such as

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5731c75196dada69cd52419d"),
"businessName" : "Test",
"createdDate" : "2015-10-04 13:48:55",
"modifiedDate" : "2016-03-03 10:37:48"
}
```

If you notice the createdDate and modifiedDate column are in YYYY-mm-dd h:i:s format (Which is coming from my Mysql Db). I need to convert the dates into ISO format.
For this, I am using the below query .

```
db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5731c75196dada69cd52419d")},
{$set : {"createdDate" : ISODate('2015-10-04 13:48:55')}} )
```

I am getting the desired result. 
Now my question is if we are having lot of documents and need to update the field value then how can we do it in iterations in Mongodb itself.
Is that possible ? Updating a single document each time will be very time-consuming. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get created at values then convert it into ISODate store it your array and then pass that array to createdDate in $in operator.

```
You  can use toISOString() of  javascript to convert values.



db.getCollection('users').update({'_id':{$in:[ObjectId('574d61acf834e66681d37804'),
    ObjectId('574d6185f834e66681d37803')]}},
    {$set : {"createdDate" :{$in:['your converted date 1','your converted date 2']}},
    {multi: true})
```